# Vapor 3 GET route for sensitive data

Tags: swift, vapor

Using numerous tutorials on Vapor 3 I've failed to figure out how I can edit output JSON, f.e. to get particular User object I create route:

```
protectedRouter.get("users", User.parameter, use: userController.user)
```

And method in `UserController`:

```
func user(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<User> {
    return try req.parameters.next(User.self)
}
```

And it, of course, sends everything that inside the User object, including email and hashed password. Great. How can I avoid this? I mean I want to send only public information about the user (name, nick, id etc...).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a separate struct representing your desired output structure. Conform that struct to `Content`. Whenever you return your User, convert it to that struct first. Adding an extension to User that does this is nice for convenience.

A common pattern emerging is to nest this struct inside the Model calling it Public. i.e.,

```
extension User {
    struct Public: Content { ... }

    func makePublic() -> Public { ... }
}
```

Your routes would then return `User.Public` instead of `User`. Note that this pattern is also useful in reverse, for creating a separate "input" representation for your User.

You can read more about this in Vapor's docs at [Vapor → Content → Dynamic Properties](https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/vapor/content/#dynamic-properties).